# How to make a SOAP request with axios the right way

Tags: axios, nestjs

Here is how I make it:

```
this.http.get<string>(url, config).toPromise();
```

Where the `config` object looks like this:

```
const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'},
    data: this.getRequestBodyFor(date)
}
```

However it errors out with `[ExceptionsHandler] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`. It does seem like the client is trying to make the request to the localhost, port 80 which is not what it is supposed to be doing. There must be some problem with the configuration.

Comment: Are you using a full URL? Is there some sort of callback happening from the SOAP call? The call in theory looks okay

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Nope, nothing like that but I've just figured out what it was...I'm supposed to be making a POST request, not a GET one. I must have written GET unconsciously, just like I'm used to do that making REST requests. It's hard to spot haha I'm going to correct the mistake and try making a request one more time.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Now I'm getting 500...Yeah I'm using the full url with no slash at the end and it gives me 500 for some reason. I'm entirely lost...

Comment: What does the error say? Is the 500 in the httpService return, or from your own server? If it is the httpService return there isn't much you can do, but if it's from your server usually a stack trace can help figure it out

Comment: Is it mandatory to use Axios? You can try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap